# Best practices for python CD/CI with machines on-site at customer

Tags: python, continuous-integration, deployment, organization, continuous-delivery

I asked this question originally on StackOverflow, and was advised to post it here instead. My question is concerning the best practices for continuous deployment and continuous integration especially with small teams.

Within our project we have a situation, where we would have to have a server running code (optimally from a git repository or something comparable) at the customer's facilities. As the server would potentially contain sensitive information, we would have to follow a specific procedure for deployment to these machines:

1. cut off connection to some of the data drives
2. connect to the internet
3. check for updates in the software
4. update and run pre- and post-deployment codes on the machine
5. disconnect from the internet
6. connect data drives again

Additionally, a proper solution would also have to include some precautions concerning security in transmission of the code itself, this, however, is optional.

I have searched for solutions online, but most of them only contain information on deployment to online services such as heroku or Microsoft Azure. In our case the use of such services is off-limits, as customer data must not be stored off-site. Another solution would be, to include handcrafted bash scripts and cronjobs on the customer's machine. This is tedious and error-prone. Moreover, a trip to the customers facilities would potentially be necessary, if deployment scripts change.

What is the best way to fulfill the described requirements?

Additional question: Is there a way to improve the routine described above in a way, which would not include cutting off the data drives, if there is no update to deliver?

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is to use a read only application image using containers like Docker. Rather than updating the system, you just deploy a new container from the updated image when you need to update, then attach that the container to the appropriate data volume.

There are two options on transferring the application image. You can either run a repository server that's accessible from both the internet and by your intranet, or you can simply export/import the application image from a tar file.

Comment: As I understand it, the solution with the tar file would have to involve driving to the customer. Is that correct?

Comment: Second question: With docker images, is there a "danger" associated with hosting the image on dockerhub? (I understood that to be the somewhat equivalent of github but for docker images?)

Comment: @1D0BE With public images, your image will be publicly listed and downloadable by anyone; you can create a private repository if you want your images to only be accessible with the appropriate credentials. Just like when using services like GitHub, the staffs of Dockerhub and their service providers may also be able to access your images. If that is a concern for you, you can use [signed images](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/trust/content_trust/) or you can run an [on-premise Docker repository](https://docs.docker.com/registry/) to better control your risks.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this answers my questions.

Answer (score 0):

Downloading software from the internet and running it on your local network is an inherently risky proposition. I am a little worried about the idea of disconnecting data drives while connected to the internet, because that may mean the risks are not well understood. Any malicious code introduced can wreak havoc on the customer's network, farm the data drives after being disconnected from the internet etc.

You may need an auditable process to demonstrate who has access to the code on your end, virus scan the deployable code before it goes out etc. Signing the docker images would be a very healthy step to make sure they are not altered in transmission.

Another option would be for the customer to build the docker images on their own using your scripts.